# Finished my first Spring MVC app - boss wants to see my unit tests - where do I start?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, spring-mvc, tdd

I just threw together a quick **Spring MVC** app as a demo to replace an internal app in my department.

Now I'm supposed to demonstrate how **Test Driven Development** works in relation to Spring MVC.

Unfortunately I didn't use **TDD** to build the demo and I'm not sure where to get started with it.

I'm using **Maven** for the build - are there any **Maven-based testing frameworks** that are easy to get started with in **Spring MVC** and that have good tutorials?

Where do I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because TDD has an huge influence how the code and methods are written, it is in most complex situations impossible to fake it! 
I mean if you do TDD then the code will be written in a kind that is is easy to test. If you don't do TDD the code will be hopefully testable too, but in a complete different way. -- So if you have some experience in TDD you will see the difference in the code.

So if there is not to much code and this TDD thing is a **really** serious requirement, then throw the code a way and do it again.

---

Anyway if you do it again or not the tools you need will be the same:

You will need a test framwork: Go with [Junit 4](http://www.junit.org/), because it is best supported by Spring (see Spring Referece: [chapter 9 Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testing)).

The integration in Maven is very easy:

Put the test cases under `src/test/java' and then (but this dependens on your style) in a parallel package structure to the classes under test. All you need is the [maven-sure-fire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) plugin.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
  </plugin>
```

May you want to do some mocking than have a look at [easyMock](http://easymock.org/) or [Jmock](http://www.jmock.org/) or [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

If you need to do integration tests, that access your application through its fronted than have a look at: [Selenium2/Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) - Therefore you need to start the server first, for example [Maven-Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) will help you. But a warning: to get your first web base integration test running, that starts the server automatically and deploy the application automatically is a hard task, and will may take you more than one day.

Comment: it's a quick test app though, so it shouldn't be that difficult to modify it to "feel like TDD"...

Comment: Guillaume: In this case, doing it again in TDD would even be easy too ;-) AND if someone is ask to presend how something works, he SHOULD have done it this way!!

Comment: I can't agree more, he's just asking for alternatives to that I suppose :) Personally, I would start again from scratch, while keeping the "old" application near and refer to it when needed.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) tutorial details how to develop a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step, which includes a step for [writing a test](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.9). Use the example therein as a model.

Answer (score 1):

Just use plane old JUnit. Maven will run the automatically as part of the build process.

Basically, you should write unit tests for each method in your code. Test each possible path through the code and the possible range of values.

If you wanted to simulate TDD, you could comment out the code and a test that fails, comment in the one or more lines of code that would make the test pass.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a testing framework (like JUnit) and a framework for mocking Spring controllers. [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) is a good choice. You can find some tutorials [here](http://blog.codehangover.com/getting-friendly-with-spring-junit-and-easymock/) and [here](http://www.abcseo.com/tech/java/testing-spring-controllers-with-easymock).

Comment: Thanks but it looks like EasyMock hasn't been updated in over a year and a half. Doesn't that make it a risk choice?

Comment: Perhaps, EasyMock is just STABLE? EasyMock is a widely used framework, as soon a you get comfortable with JUnit or (www.testng.org/) you should certainly dig into it. BTW TDD tries to write the test before the code ...

Comment: I tested all the Java mocking frameworks, my favorite is (by far) JMock 2. Have a look (http://www.jmock.org/) - but be warned if you're a beginner, there's quite a learning curve from plain junit to mocking.